# JQM - JQuery Mobile 1.4.2 infinite refresh, is it a bug?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I couldn't find any other info about anyone with this problem... I am not using .page() anywhere, i even unlinked my exterenal javascript file, and it still happens.

I navigate using a navbar and randomly (not always) it will start reloading the page in an infinite loop. and there is this 1 page, that has nothing special that will always happen if i press f5 to reload it, but if i come from another page... it doesnt happen o O it's so weird.

I'm using php and jqm 1.4.2 with jquery 1.10.2. I would post code, but can't really pinpoint anything.

On the page that i can press f5/refresh and it always does this bug, i tried removing all content, and php, other than includes/header/footer partials and it still happens...., removing my js from header and it still happens, the only conclusion I can come to is jqm 1.4.2 jquery or my php settings, which i am clueless on what to do. Any idea? This site used to be in jqm 1.2.0 and don't remember having this problem then.

EDIT: It seems removing the _footer.php partial stopped the bug this is its contents:

```
<?php
$navCSS = "ui-btn-active ui-state-persist";
?>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="quarts.php" class="cui-icon ui-nodisc-icon <?php echo($pageID == "quarts")?$navCSS:""; ?>" data-icon="quarts" data-prefetch="true" data-transition="fade">Quarts</a></li>
            <li><a href="nouvelle.php" class="cui-icon ui-nodisc-icon <?php echo($pageID == "nouv")?$navCSS:""; ?>" data-icon="nouv" data-prefetch="true" data-transition="fade">Nouvelle</a></li>
            <li><a href="disponible.php" class="cui-icon ui-nodisc-icon <?php echo($pageID == "disponible")?$navCSS:""; ?>" data-icon="dispo" data-prefetch="true" data-transition="fade">Dispo.</a></li>
            <li><a href="paies.php" class="cui-icon ui-nodisc-icon <?php echo($pageID == "paie")?$navCSS:""; ?>" data-icon="paie" data-prefetch="true" data-transition="fade">Paies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pushMenu" id="push" class="cui-icon ui-nodisc-icon <?php echo($pageID == "code" || $pageID == "docs" || $pageID == "profil")?$navCSS:""; ?>" data-icon="autre" data-transition="slide">Autres...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- page end -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT: removing data-prefetch stops the issue,** but i wanted to prefetch pages for smooth navigation and make it feel like an app, why does it cause this issue?

Comment: Pls add more details and code.

Comment: Try removing prefetch in links.

Comment: I removed prefetch, and that stops the refresh issue on this page, but then i noticed that my pages are all screwed up, some pages have 2 pages in one and some page has the header of the previous page or the content of the previous page. I have no idea what's going on. Re-adding prefetch fixes that.

Comment: In this case, create an external footer. When you have the same footer for each page with prefetch, it will prefetch the same page/link several times.

Comment: This footer is external i use php require_once to include it on each page after the ui-content closing div. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: It's internal since you include it within page div. place footer div outside any page div (inside body) but you need to initialize it `$(function() { $("[data-role=footer]").toolbar().enhanceWithin(); });`.

Comment: the buttons sizes/positions are ok but the colors/styling is off when i do this, i also tried prepending it to page container dynamically and same issue.

Comment: Add `data-theme="a"` or "b" to footer div.

Comment: Allright it works now! thank you! if you write an answer I will accept it. but I am having other problems with multiple pages being in the same page that is probably not related to this question.

Comment: If you have another problem, go ahead and post a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External pages/links are being *prefetched* several times as you are using the same *navbar* internally for each page. Your solution is to use an *External* footer and *navbar* which can be accessed from any internal or external page.

```
<body> <!-- or page container div -->
  <div data-role="page">
  </div>

  <!-- external footer -->
  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
     <div data-role="navbar">
     </div>
  </div>
```

When using *external* widgets, you need to *initialize* them manually by calling `.toolbar()` and then `.enhanceWithin()` to *initialize* inner widgets.

```
$(function () {
  $("[data-role=footer]").toolbar().enhanceWithin();
});
```

Comment: Actually, once i fixed the tabs(from my other question) this issue doesnt happen anymore. Do you think I should still make it external?

Comment: @user it's up to you. Instead if adding the same html markup to each page, you add once only.

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, it seems it was working because I was using absolute path for links, now that I removed the absolute paths and used normal links it came back, so i took it out of the page div and it works again!